# Tcl - passing curly braces into a variable within a regsub command

Tags: tcl

I need to pass a regular expression as a variable within a `regsub` command. I want to eliminate the brackets from `cap` variable, but I am unable to pass the curly braces within the `match` variable.

```
set cap {[equality choice control]}
set match {\[}
regsub -all $match $cap "" cap
puts $cap
```

The reason for doing this is that I am building a `proc` and I need to pass the regex as an argument.

Comment: Your example doesn't really show anything being done to curly braces. If the answer below is answering the wrong question - try being more explicit about the expected output and provided inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are special in regular expressions as well as Tcl. To match a literal bracket you need to escape it in the regular expression and it needs separate escaping in Tcl.

```
% set match {[}
[
% regsub -all $match $cap ""
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: brackets [] not balanced

% set match {\[}
\[
% regsub -all $match $cap ""
equality choice control]
```

You could also use quotes but ensure you deal with the Tcl escaping requirements. ie: `set match "\\\["`

Note: for a simple substitution you may find `string map` easier to use:

```
set cap [string map [list "\[" ""] $cap]
```

would achieve the same effect.